# JQuery AutoComplete with SQL

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using JQuery on my ASP.net page and I want to know if there is a way I could use AutoComplete with SQL.  To be exact, I am doing "select" on the database, and I will have an array of string and I want to use the array with the AutoComplete to populate strings as user types.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to get jQuery Autocomplete functionality is to use the [jQuery UI control](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote).  It uses jQuery's Ajax functionality to call to a server-side function that returns an array of values.

The code to make a call to a datasource (such as SQL Server or MySQL) looks like this (from the jQueryUI documentation):

```
$( "#myInputBox" ).autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a new WCF web service that will wrap around your Stored Procedure / Dynamic query. You can then call that with JQuery autocomplete:

[JQuery Autocomplete with WCF](http://geekswithblogs.net/apopovsky/archive/2009/06/16/jquery-autocomplete-with-wcf-services.aspx)